# Как получить объекты из коллекции по значению свойства DateTime объекта?

Tags: c#, linq, коллекции

Есть коллекция

```
ObservableCollection<MyObject> data = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
```

в неё добавляются элементы

```
for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{
    var obj = new MyObject()
    {
        // Создаётся объект даты времени без секунд
        // Затем секунды добавляются
        time = new DateTime(2017, 05, 17, 12, 00, 00).AddSeconds(i),
        value = i
    }
    data.add(obj);
}
```

Объект элемента

```
class MyObject
{
    DateTime time { get; set; }
    Double value { get; set; }
}
```

Далее нужно найти все элементы из коллекции в которых время от 12.00.03 до 12.00.15 
Пробую так

```
var newData = data.Where(x => x.time.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds > new DateTime(2017, 05, 17, 12, 00, 03).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds &&
                            x.time.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds < new DateTime(2017, 05, 17, 12, 00, 15).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds);
```

не получается

как получить range объектов из коллекции по значению time объекта Object?

Comment: Вы специально использовали имя класса Object? Не хорошо это, да и читать код тяжело. Есть подозрение что беда у вас как раз в этом. Object - встроенный класс, так что очень просто не заметить где ваш класс, а где системный. Скорее всего ошибка в этом, а так вроде все логично

Comment: Изменил код. Я использую другое название, просто тут так написал.

Answer (score 2):

Объявление полей класса без модификатора доступа равнозначно их объявлению с модификатором `private`.

Сделайте их публичными:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public Double value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается всё работает
Даже не обязательно делать свойства public

Первый раз когда было сравнение без TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds не возвращалось ничего
поставил точку остановки и в Results View ничего не было

потом я просто туда почему-то не смотрел, ориентировался на другие свойства

Сейчас глянул, всё работает, возвращается правильный результат

Спасибо!

Comment: Магия! А еще говорят, что программисты не колдуны :)